# All possible combinations of letters

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to repeat 2 letters in a word of 4 characters using SQL Server.

e.g. If the 2 letters are A,B

```
Result: 
AAAA
BBBB
ABBB
BBAA
AABB
AABB
and so on.
.
.
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

All combinations of two letters

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Letter char(1))

INSERT @t(Letter)VALUES('A'),('B')

SELECT l1.Letter+l2.Letter+l3.Letter+l4.Letter Word
--SELECT CONCAT(l1.Letter,l2.Letter,l3.Letter,l4.Letter) Word
FROM @t l1
CROSS JOIN @t l2
CROSS JOIN @t l3
CROSS JOIN @t l4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTEs for this, so no temporary table is needed:

```
with l as (
      select v.l
      from (values ('A'), ('B')) v(l)
     )
select (l1.l + l2.l + l3.l + l4.l) as result
from l l1 cross join
     l l2 cross join
     l l3 cross join
     l l4;
```